# Why can't the compilation of Ryzom find 'X11/Xatom.h' on Mac?

Tags: macos, ryzom

Trying to compile Ryzom after the merger, and it's yelling at me again. Any suggestions?

```
[ 10%] Building CXX object nel/src/misc/CMakeFiles/nelmisc.dir/config_file/cf_lexical.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object nel/src/misc/CMakeFiles/nelmisc.dir/config_file/config_file.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../../lib/libnelmisc.a
[ 10%] Built target nelmisc
Scanning dependencies of target nel3d_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Building CXX object nel/src/3d/CMakeFiles/nel3d_pch_dephelp.dir/std3d.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../../lib/libnel3d_pch_dephelp.a
[ 10%] Built target nel3d_pch_dephelp
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_nel3d
[ 10%] Generating std3d.h.gch
[ 10%] Built target pch_Generate_nel3d
Scanning dependencies of target nel_drv_opengl_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Building CXX object nel/src/3d/driver/opengl/CMakeFiles/nel_drv_opengl_pch_dephelp.dir/stdopengl.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../../../../lib/libnel_drv_opengl_pch_dephelp.a
[ 10%] Built target nel_drv_opengl_pch_dephelp
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_nel_drv_opengl
[ 10%] Generating stdopengl.h.gch
[ 10%] Built target pch_Generate_nel_drv_opengl
Scanning dependencies of target nel_drv_opengl
[ 10%] Building CXX object nel/src/3d/driver/opengl/CMakeFiles/nel_drv_opengl.dir/driver_opengl.cpp.o
/Users/jennifer/Downloads/ryzom/ryzom/code/nel/src/3d/driver/opengl/driver_opengl.cpp:2515:3: warning: #warning "OpenGL Driver: Missing Mac Implementation for ATI version retrieval" 
[ 10%] Building CXX object nel/src/3d/driver/opengl/CMakeFiles/nel_drv_opengl.dir/driver_opengl_extension.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object nel/src/3d/driver/opengl/CMakeFiles/nel_drv_opengl.dir/driver_opengl_inputs.cpp.o
/Users/jennifer/Downloads/ryzom/ryzom/code/nel/src/3d/driver/opengl/driver_opengl_inputs.cpp:21:24: error: X11/Xatom.h: No such file or directory
/Users/jennifer/Downloads/ryzom/ryzom/code/nel/src/3d/driver/opengl/driver_opengl_inputs.cpp:802:3: warning: #warning "OpenGL Driver: Missing Mac Implementation for getDoubleClickDelay" 
make[2]: *** [nel/src/3d/driver/opengl/CMakeFiles/nel_drv_opengl.dir/driver_opengl_inputs.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Why can't the compilation of Ryzom find 'X11/Xatom.h' on Mac?

Comment: I think that *"error: X11/Xatom.h: No such file or directory"* is pretty clear. You are missing a dependency. I know there is a lot of output and some of it is pretty mysterious, but you have to *read* it.

Comment: @dmckee In fact, Ryzom is using Carbon and Cocoa APIs under Mac OS X so there shouldn't be any X11 header included here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your report !

You're right, it's a bug and I wonder why nobody got it before... Perhaps because they installed X Windows headers before compiling Ryzom.

I committed a fix to Hg so you just have to pull/update again and it should be ok :)

That's easy to fix compilation errors when reporters post exactly what we need to know to fix it :)